# Feed reader that allows subscription to only certain categories of posts from a blog

Tags: rss, feeds

Often I am only interested in certain categories of posts from a blog. Is there any feed reader that allows this? Also, is this information even included in RSS/ATOM?

Comment: Would think this question be better if you had a reader in mind, wanted to know if it was possible and then leave a note saying if not, suggest an alternative.

Comment: Both RSS and Atom do have a `category` element, although it's optional.  Blogs that have categories are likely to include it.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any reader that has such capacities. Sometimes blogs themselves offer a feed specific to one category.

I personally use [Feed Rinse](http://www.feedrinse.com/) for some feeds to filter out posts that I don't want. There you can **block** (or allow) items **based on title, tag, author or content**. Maybe that could help you as well.